# Using mockito; is it possible to mock a method that takes a lambda as a parameter and assert variables captured by the lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, mockito

I have a method that looks that looks something like:

```
public Response methodA(ParamObject po, Supplier<Response> supplier)
```

the `Supplier` contains a call to a method on another class.

I am attempting to wrap some code in the `Supplier` in a more complex set of logic, something akin to a Strategy pattern, it does make the code easier to follow.

It looks something like:

```
public Controller {    
   private Helper helper;
   private Delegate delegate;

   public void doSomething() {
     ParamObject po = ....
     delegate.methodA(po, () -> {
         helper.doSomethingElse(v1, v2);
     }
   }

}
```

In my test for `Controller` I have mocked both `Helper` and `Delegate`, I wish to validate that `helper.doSomething` is called with the correct parameter values, and then return a mocked response.

Given that `delegate` is a mock, the `Supplier` is never actually executed, so no verification of the calls to `helper` can be mocked or verified.

Is it possible to do this?  It feels like I should be able to tell mockito to capture the lambda, and or the variables the lambda itself captured and assert they are the right values return my mock response if they are the values I was looking for.

Comment: This should be feasible using a `Mock` object. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#mockito_verify) is a tutorial on this topic.

Comment: Isn't that a simple assert that your mocked helper got a certain method call (nothing to do with the lambda)?

Comment: @zapl no I dont think so, as no call to ```mockHelper.doSomething``` will happening, as ```delegate``` is also mocked.  I will make the question clearer

Comment: You want to verify a call to `helper.doSomething`, but cannot verify anything on `helper`... this is a contradiction.

Comment: Potentially yes; I guess I was hoping I could in some "magic way" tell mockito to execute the ```suppiler``` then mocking would work normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your class Helper looks like this:

```
public class Helper {
    public Response doSomethingElse(String v1, String v2) {
        // rest of the method here
    }
}
```

Then it could be done like this:

```
Helper helper = mock(Helper.class);
// a and b are the expected parameters
when(helper.doSomethingElse("a", "b")).thenReturn(new Response());
// a and c are not the expected parameters
when(helper.doSomethingElse("a", "c")).thenThrow(new AssertionError());

Delegate delegate = mock(Delegate.class);
// Whatever the parameters provided, simply execute the supplier to 
// get the response to provide and to get an AssertionError if the
// parameters are not the expected ones
when(delegate.methodA(any(), any())).then(
    new Answer<Response>() {
        @Override
        public Response answer(final InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
            return ((Supplier<Response>) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[1]).get();
        }
    }
);

Controller controller = new Controller();
controller.helper = helper;
controller.delegate = delegate;
controller.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

With lamda functions, you can also make this look a bit nicer and more compact - following on from the other excellent answer.

```
final Delegate delegate = mock(Delegate.class);
when(delegate.methodA(any(), any(Supplier.class))).then(
    (invocationOnMock) -> ((Supplier) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[1]).get()
);
```